# Installation metro app package for other users

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, sideloading

I have two registered users on my PC and I have no problems installing packages via sideloader on Admin account but when I'm trying to install it on other account nothing happens (I mean it's not being installed, although in sideloader I get information that "it has been successfully installed).
Am I doing something wrong?
Or there is other solution to solve this.

(On 2nd account there is no VS installed).

Additionally, when I'm trying to Addpackage via PowerShell:

> "The package is not digitally signed or its signature is corrupted."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is the discussion forum in microsoft

[insatll problem](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_store/can-guest-account-use-store-apps/b1947bc6-e5f0-4f77-bbf2-6a6d6687f252)

They talk abput the same problem ..

and also

you can go through this [apps instal and find](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows-8/why-find-install-app-windows-store)

Let me knwo if the links are useful :) else ill give another search

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but in the end the problem was that the app is targeting windows 8.1 while I'm trying to install it on windows 8.